# Can a vendor send an invoice file that can become my bill?

Tags: gnucash

Both I, and a vendor I do business with, use GnuCash. It would save me a lot of labor if my vendor could send me an invoice file made by his GnuCash installation that can be read by my GnuCash installation and become a bill in accounts payable there.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

What answer to dou expect? Yes, he CAN - it is possible. It is also unlikely because as a vendor he will streamline his operations, and your unusual request is exactly that - unusual. So time spent for no gain.

Comment: If he can, what is the procedure for doing so? Right now I have to manually enter a bill in accounts payable for every Invoice he sends me.

Comment: There may not eve nbe a prodecure - GnuCash is open souce, so you may have to extend the source code. But this makes it EXPENSIVE - not IMPOSSIBLE.

Comment: I can't see any way for a normal GnuCash user (your vendor) to export his invoice except as an HTML document, or of course as a printed form or PDF.  Maybe with a deep dive into the source code it would be possible.
However, you can ease your workload in creating a new invoice in GnuCash by "Duplicating" an existing invoice from the same vendor.

Comment: Use something like pdfbox to extract the pdf text and reformat/import the output